# How can I accept these lines won't diverge from one another?

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, analysis, functions

UPDATE 21/04/2019:

While I was trying to picture in my mind the following function $  \ f(x,y)=y^{2}x\\  $.
That seemed a pretty function, one that was easy-eanough to just shape it up in my head. Well, slices along the $x$ direction will give narrower parabolas as $x$ increase. Slices on the $y$ axes will give us steeper lines as $y$ increases.
Anyway while dreaming about this function, a silly thought started to annoy me and I couldn't manage to get over it, as much as I tried to elaborate an argument against it. This is probably one of the akward scenarios we meet when we try to face the concept of infinity.
My reasoing went something like that.

Suppose we want to graphically construct the function $  \ f(x,y)=y^{2}x \ \\ $ in the following way:
For any $y_{i}$ along the $y$ axis, we draw the $ \ \Re \rightarrow \Re \  $ function  $ \ z(x)=y_{i}^{2}x\ \\ $ on on the $z=y_{i}$ plane.
Being $y_{i}$ a constant on the $z=y_{i}$, $ \ z(x)=y_{i}^{2}x\ \\ $ is just a line through the origin on that plane. But $z(x)=y_{i}^{2}x $ is indeed the function we obtain when we slice $  \ f(x,y)=y^{2}x \ \\ $ with the $z=y_{i}$ plane.
So in a sense  $  \ f(x,y)=y^{2}x \ \\ $ is a graphic limit of a succession of these lines as we let the difference between $y_{i+1}-y_{i}$ go to zero, isn't it?

Summing up: For every For any $y_{i}$ along the $y$ axis, we draw the line $ \ z(x)=y_{i}^{2}x\ \\ $ on on the $z=y_{i}$ plane. As any 2 consecutive lines get infinitely close $(y_{i+1}-y_{i} \rightarrow 0)$  for $y_{i}$ in $[-\infty,\infty]$ we should

get our $  \ f(x,y)=y^{2}x \ \\ $.
My concern regards the fact that these lines for $x$ that goes to infinity seems to inevitably diverge from one another. As much as we get each line close to its next, there will be an $x$ for which  $ \ z(x)=y_{i+1}^{2}x\ \\ $ will diverge from  $ \ z(x)=y_{i}^{2}x\ \\ $.
This event will crash all good property of  our function. That said I know that this is a really simple function mathematically, well-described and well-shaped,
and this is the reason why I am botherd by this thought to which I can't give a satisying answer that would make me say " Of course they won't diverge!!".
I sketched some drawings that may help to represent my point and how my confusion arised.
I've sketched some drawings to let my confusion be more tangible to others.
Here I drew each line with a step distance of $0.1$ for $y$ in $[1,2]$

[image]

Here I drew each line with a step distance of $0.01$ for $y$ in $[1,1.1]$

[image]
If you have some ideas, some advices, that you want to share that may help to not get stuck dreaming about "How is this possible?" or that will help to convince yourself that this is completely "normal". Or just to accept it as it is.
Unless it may provide some particular insights, I'm not in search of mathematical proofs, but of an informal argument that will convince you....Even though if you think that the only way is focusing on mathematical definitions is the way to go feel free to elaborate on it

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I'll try to edit in order to make it clearer

Comment: The divergence you mention has nothing to do with continuity. Topological matter is infinitely elastic.

Comment: Sorry but the EDIT you made is still not asking a precise question. And to be honest, is barely understandable.

Comment: I did not take any course in topology, so I don't know that. My question is just on an intuition level....Don't know if it was clear, but as divergence I intended the fact that if we draw the lines $f(x)=y_{i}^{2}x$ through $y_{i}$ for $i$ in $[0,\infty]$ as $y_{i+i}-y_{i}$ goes to zero and we reach out from the $y$ axis still $y_{i}$ and $y_{i+1}$ will not be indistinguishable..

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was confident, but I'm always open to criticism, if you want to address misconceptions, I'm glad to hear

Answer (score 0):

You can represent the function $f(x,y)$ as a surface $(x,y,f(x,y))$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The fact that $f$ is a continuous function of $x$ and $y$ does *not* mean that lines on this surface with  a constant value for $y$ will always remain close to one another. It means that around any point $P=(x_0, y_0, f(x_0,y_0))$ on this surface we can find a small patch $Q(P,\delta) = \{(x,y,f(x,y)) : |(x,y)- (x_0,y_0)| < \delta \}$ such that $f(x,y)$ is close to $f(x_0,y_0)$ everywhere in this patch. Technically, given any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $\delta(\epsilon)$ such that $|f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)| < \epsilon \space \forall \space (x,y,f(x,y)) \in Q(P, \delta(\epsilon))$.

Continuity is a local property of the surface - it says nothing about how the surface behaves globally.

Comment: Ok maybe I was not clear in addressing where my confusion arise... Let's say for every $y_{i}$ along the $y$ axis we draw on the $<x,z>$ plane across $y_{i}$ the "slice function" $f(x)=y_{i}^{2}x$  and then let the difference between $y_{i+1}$ and $y_{i}$ go to zero. Wouldn't we get the original function?

Comment: @GabrieleScarlatti If you make $|y_{i+1}-y_i|$ small enough then you can make the $y_{i+1}$ and $y_i$ slices as close as you like at a given value of $x$. You cannot make the two slices close along their whole lengths, but that is a global property, unrelated to local continuity. You may be thinking about something like *uniform* continuity, which is a global property.

Comment: Ok but for this function the cross section on the plane $y_{i}$ will always be $f(x)=y_{i}^{2}x$ for $x$ in $[-\infty, \infty]$ and  for $y_{i+1}$ will always be $f(x)=y_{i+1}^{2}x$ for $x$ in $[-\infty, \infty]$, not only near  $y_{i}$ or $y_{i+1}$...or not? ps: I did not downvoted your answer and I thank you for trying helping out

Answer (score 0):

To me it appears  you are stuck about the basic contour behaviour in a global sense, not linking to limit tendencies of families of lines locally.

By differently assigned values look ***at projections*** for a constant coordinate intersections which are better guides in contour determination.

1. x=const ; you should see parabolas holding or spilling water depending on x>0 or x<0
2. y=const ; you should see straight lines. y=0 should be the mirror plane, y can be >0 or <0
3. z=const ;  a sort of deformed hyperbolas should be seen in quadrants same sign as x

These are drawn in Geogebra3D,scaled 20 times for shallow topography.

[image: Geogebra3D]